# Check difference in xPaths, inside yaml file

Tags: python, xml, xpath, yaml

Is there a way in Python to check differences between two *Yaml* files, that contain *xPaths* such as:

The first file, file1:

```
interfaces:
  oper-status:
    xpath: //rpc-reply/interface-information/*
```

The second file, file2:

```
interfaces:
  oper-status:
    xpath: //rpc-reply/interface-information/physical-interface/oper-status/text()
```

Is there a way to overwrite one *xPath* with another if it is more specific? (I would like the *xPath* from the second file to be used as it is more specific)

Would appreciate some help

Comment: You have to define what you mean by *more specific*. The two XPaths you show select different nodes (first one potentially selects a `<physical-interface>` element, second one some text value within that element – however, the first XPath can also select an element complete unrelated to `<physical-interface>`).

Comment: So i want to have a default xPath, such as file 1, which will grab all the information. But, if a more specific xPath is present like in file 2 i want it to use that. By more specific i am meaning a longer xPath returning just that specific bit of data instead of all interface-information, it returns just the oper-status.

Comment: Would „strip XPaths of trailing `*`, then check whether the longer starts with the shorter XPath“ do what you want? Doing a general comparison of XPaths taking all its features into account can be a complex endeavour.

Comment: Sounds like its on the right track, but i am not sure how to go about comparing the lengths of xpaths, within yaml files. Is there a way to transform an xPath into a string, and checking the len()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In YAML, the XPath is just a scalar that can be loaded into a string. So you could do something like this:

```
import yaml

file1 = """
interfaces:
  oper-status:
    xpath: //rpc-reply/interface-information/*
"""

file2 = """
interfaces:
  oper-status:
    xpath: //rpc-reply/interface-information/physical-interface/oper-status/text()
"""

loaded1 = yaml.safe_load(file1)
loaded2 = yaml.safe_load(file2)

def select_more_specific(xpath1, xpath2):
    stripped1 = xpath1.strip("*")
    stripped2 = xpath2.strip("*")
    if len(stripped1) > len(stripped2):
        stripped1, stripped2 = stripped2, stripped1
    if stripped2.startswith(stripped1):
        return stripped2
    return None

def get_xpath(root):
    return root["interfaces"]["oper-status"]["xpath"]

def set_xpath(root, value):
    root["interfaces"]["oper-status"]["xpath"] = value

more_specific = select_more_specific(get_xpath(loaded1), get_xpath(loaded2))
if more_specific is not None:
    set_xpath(loaded1, more_specific)
    set_xpath(loaded2, more_specific)

print("# processed file 1:")
print(yaml.dump(loaded1, sort_keys=False))
print("# processed file 2:")
print(yaml.dump(loaded2, sort_keys=False))
```

Comment: Thanks i should be able to work with this to get what i need. Massive help!